# which version of python is used when I run it in interpreter?

Tags: python, bash, version

I am confused in trying to understand which python version is used when I run them in interpreter?
That is, how the shell decides which python version to load when I have more than one versions.
I have snapshot of my /usr/bin. It has atleast two different python versions2.5 and 2.6.
I have not specified anything in my .bashrc to choose which one from.
when I execute python command on bash shell, python interpreter opens up, but loads with version 2.6.
How is this detected by shell?
If I want to change versions, how will I do that? That is, I want to change the default version
lastly what kind of files are these in /usr/bin/python. I tried to open them in editor and I see some @@@. I have read many posts here but some makes me confusing.

```
ls /usr/bin/python
python            python2.5         python2.6         pythonw           pythonw2.6        
python-config     python2.5-config  python2.6-config  pythonw2.5   

python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: type `which python`, it will give you the default interpreter.

Comment: And after typing `which python`, go update your version of python!  Unless you need to support old code, it is best to start writing new programs in the latest version.

Comment: kindly see my question. I am asking how the shell decides which python version to load? I dont want to remove old version. I want to be able to switch between them

Answer (score 2):

To know which version is used by default, type

```
which python
```

To use another one, use the full path when invoking them:

```
/usr/bin/python/python2.5 myfile.py
/usr/bin/python/python2.6 myfile.py
etc.
```

If you want to change the default, you can create an alias in `~/.bashrc` for example:

```
my_python='/usr/bin/python/python2.7'
```

**or better** change the link direction of `/usr/bin/python` (or whatever comes from `which python`). It is a link, so link it to the exact version you need.

```
ln -s /prefered/path/of/python /usr/bin/python
```

The files you see in `/usr/bin/python` are executables. You can do the following to see this:

```
file /usr/bin/python/python2.5
```

In my case:

```
$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to `python2.7'
$ file /usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xf66a10f2c444b2329b25ab6790abb7fbb4fe3f78, stripped
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question above. how to change the default version in bashrc and why does shell load python 2.6 in my case, instead of python 2.5 when I have not explicitly specified to use python 2.6 in my .bashrc

Comment: OK now I see. Check my updated answer in "**or better**" to change the link direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
python --version
```

Then head on over to your .bashrc (should be in your home directory) and add:

```
alias python='[your path]'
```

for me I have:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python2.7'
```

Just make sure you say:

```
source ./bashrc
```

to apply your changes.